# How do I disable browser hot module reloading for nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt project that uses webpack.

I run `npm run dev` which launches a dev server that listens to `localhost:3000`.

I then use a reverse proxy (nginx) to serve this app through a domain name locally (e.g. I can access the app in my browser using `dashboard.com/`, which forwards the requests to `localhost:3000`).

When navigating through my app, it sometimes take 40 seconds to get a response. **When I checked the nginx logs, the path to `/__webpack_hmr/client` were at fault.**

1. Why does this page take 40 seconds to load every now and then (not always, but very often)?
2. How do I fix/disable this?

**I don't need hot module reloading as I'd rather hit `F5` to refresh the page instantly than wait 40 seconds to refresh a page because of this module.**

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "----",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "----",
  "author": "----",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt --no-hot ",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-0",
    "debounce": "^1.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "pug-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is my nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dashboard.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting in nuxt's reddit and discord, one of the core developers of nuxt provided the solution below in github.

In the `nuxt.config.js` file, remove the `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` from webpack's plugins:

```
export default {
    ...
    build: {
          extend(config) {
              const hmrIndex = config.plugins.findIndex(p => p.constructor.name === 'HotModuleReplacementPlugin')
              config.plugins.splice(hmrIndex, 1)
          } 
      }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Now it says, and throws error that hot module is disabled. Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled.